# How is the Gamma function related to the Golden Ratio?

Tags: gamma-function, golden-ratio

I was researching the Gamma function and came across this in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Minima_and_maxima):

> The positive solution to Γ(z − 1) = Γ(z + 1) is z = φ ≈ +1.618, the golden ratio, and the common value is Γ(φ − 1) = Γ(φ + 1) = φ! ≈ +1.44922960226989660037.

This is blowing my mind. My mind was blown learning $e^{iπ} = -1$ and the link between the Riemann Zeta Function and prime numbers. There is some sort of link between factorials and the golden ratio? Not only is φ a solution to the equation, but φ! is the value of each side?!?

The citation link goes to the list of integer sequences at OEIS, which doesn't give any indication (that I can find) as to why.

What is the link between the the Golden Ratio and the Gamma function?

Comment: from $z \Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z+1)$   we also have $(z-1) \Gamma(z-1) = \Gamma(z) .$ So that $z (z-1) \Gamma(z-1) = \Gamma(z+1).$ The specific value of $z$ you want has $z(z-1) = 1 ,$ or $z^2 - z - 1 = 0$